# Python 3 - Issues writing to files using the stdout argument of subprocess.call module

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to automate running *snmpwalk* against several hosts on my penetration testing lab. Basically what I want to do is to give my python script a list of target IPs (in the form of a text file), have it run snmpwalk against them, and store the results in separate files that I create (one per target IP). Here's a portion of my code that runs the tool against the target IPs contained in the `live_list` object file:

```
def run_snmpwalk(selection):
    # Rewind file
    live_list.seek(0)
    if selection == '1':
            i = 0
            for line in live_list:

                    tgt_host = line.strip("/\n")
                    file_obj_array[i].write('[+] SNMPWalk user enumeration for IP:  ' + tgt_host + ' \n')
                    print('[+] Attempting to enumerate users from IP: ' + tgt_host)
                    exit_code = subprocess.call(['snmpwalk', '-c', 'public', '-v1', tgt_host, '1.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.2.25'], stdout=file_obj_array[i])
                    i += 1
                    if exit_code == 0:
                            print('[+] Success')
                    else:
                            print('[+] Something went wrong while executing snmpwalk ')
```

As crappy as it might be, the code above works as I intended to, except for one little detail that I can't seem to fix.

The line below uses the `subprocess.call` module with the `stdout`parameter set to the file I previously created to contain the output of the command:

```
subprocess.call(['snmpwalk', '-c', 'public', '-v1', tgt_host, '1.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.2.25'], stdout=file_obj_array[i])
```

And this next line is supposed to write a header in the file to which the output of the previous command is being dumped to:

```
file_obj_array[i].write('[+] SNMPWalk user enumeration for IP:  ' + tgt_host + ' \n')
```

However, instead of ending up with a header, the line above ends up at the bottom of the file, despite it being executed before the `subprocess.call` line. Here's a sample output file of the function above:

```
iso.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.2.25.1.1.5.71.117.101.115.116 = STRING: "Guest"
iso.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.2.25.1.1.6.97.117.115.116.105.110 = STRING: "austin"
iso.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.2.25.1.1.9.73.85.83.82.95.83.82.86.50 = STRING: "IUSR_SRV2"
iso.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.2.25.1.1.9.73.87.65.77.95.83.82.86.50 = STRING: "IWAM_SRV2"
iso.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.2.25.1.1.13.65.100.109.105.110.105.115.116.114.97.116.111.114 = STRING: "Administrator"
iso.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.2.25.1.1.14.84.115.73.110.116.101.114.110.101.116.85.115.101.114 = STRING: "TsInternetUser"

[+] SNMPWalk user enumeration for IP:  10.11.1.128
```

I can't figure out why `subprocess.call` manages to write lines to the file before `file_obj_array[i].write`, even though it comes after it in the for loop.

Any ideas would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to flush buffers:

```
def run_snmpwalk(selection, live_list, file_obj_array):
    # Rewind file
    live_list.seek(0)
    if selection == '1':
        for line, file_obj in zip(live_list, file_obj_array):
            tgt_host = line.strip("/\n")
            file_obj.write('[+] SNMPWalk user enumeration for IP:  {}\n'.format(tgt_host))
            file_obj.flush()
            print('[+] Attempting to enumerate users from IP: {}'.format(tgt_host))
            exit_code = subprocess.call(['snmpwalk', '-c', 'public', '-v1', tgt_host, '1.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.2.25'], stdout=file_obj)
            if exit_code == 0:
                print('[+] Success')
            else:
                print('[+] Something went wrong while executing snmpwalk ')
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! that fixed the issue.